# linking inside PDF generated by pdflatex

Tags: pdftex

I have seen some PDF documents where figure numbers, citations, table numbers are highlighted and clickable. The click on any of these colored text allows one to jump to the resulting location.

What package I can use to for these features?

Comment: The `hyperref` Package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the answer already has been given in a comment by [Juri Robl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5042/juri-robl), I'd like to add some short sentences:

Yes, you get a linked PDF using the package hyperref. If you use texlive (and maybe as well with MikTeX), you get the documentation typing `texdoc hyperref` on the command line. The maintainer is [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek), who is really active here.

There is one important thing to know and that is the reason for writing this answer (except that there is one question less without an answer): **Make sure that `\usepackage{hyperref}` is the last package to be loaded.** hyperref redefines a lot of things, so your code will probably wind up if you load hyperref somewhere else!

---

EDIT: The comment of Peter Grill is important as well: there are some packages, which have to be loaded after hyperref, see here: [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill)

Comment: Another important thing to know is that the using cross-referencing sometimes sets the bounding box (the part of the document your link refers to) wrong. For images you can use the `hypcap` package in conjunction with `\capstart` (inside your figure environment) to link to the top of the picture, instead of the caption. For text, use `\Hy@raisedlink` (look it up, you will have to define your own macro for this). Happy referencing! `:-)`

Comment: Note that `hyperref` should be the _last_ package loaded _most_ of the time: [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before).

Comment: @1010011010 Thanks a lot for such a nice and detailed answer.